# How to Address "Refused to Set Unsafe Header: Connection"?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, prototypejs

I'm using Prototype combined with CodeIgniter to submit an AJAX request. My browser is Chrome. I'm receiving an error in the console that reads "Refused to set Unsafe Header: Connection". Here is the Ajax Request line:

```
new Ajax.Request('/vbs/index.php/signup/get_ratecenters',{method:'POST', evalScripts:true})
```

I've attempted to set the type to synchronous, but received the same error.

Can someone assist? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There's only one code fragment in [prototype.js (1.7.0.0)](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js) that attempts to set a `Connection: close` header

```
if (this.method == 'post') {
  headers['Content-type'] = this.options.contentType +
    (this.options.encoding ? '; charset=' + this.options.encoding : '');

  /* Force "Connection: close" for older Mozilla browsers to work
   * around a bug where XMLHttpRequest sends an incorrect
   * Content-length header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
   */
  if (this.transport.overrideMimeType &&
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/Gecko\/(\d{4})/) || [0,2005])[1] < 2005)
        headers['Connection'] = 'close';
}
```

If you're using a local copy of prototype.js you could change the code fragment to

```
if (this.method == 'post') {
  headers['Content-type'] = this.options.contentType +
    (this.options.encoding ? '; charset=' + this.options.encoding : '');

  /* Force "Connection: close" for older Mozilla browsers to work
   * around a bug where XMLHttpRequest sends an incorrect
   * Content-length header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
   */
  if (this.transport.overrideMimeType &&
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/Gecko\/(\d{4})/) || [0,2005])[1] < 2005)
  {
        alert("Yes, this is it.");
            if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/Gecko\/(\d{4})/) ) {
                alert("navigator");
            }
        headers['Connection'] = 'close';
  }
}
```

and see if it's really the cause.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you load `/vbs/index.php/signup/get_ratecenters` directly in your browser?

I [read somewhere online](http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/site-essentials-package/ajax-anywhere/1076-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection) that "Refused to set Unsafe Header: Connection" is a warning that the HTTP "Connection" header cannot be set, but doesn't mean the request will not be processed, so it's possible something else is going on here?

Check `/vbs/index.php/signup/get_ratecenters` and make sure it returns valid JavaScript code. Execute that code in the Chrome console and make sure it is error free... possibly here's a different error here.

Comment: Josh, do you have any updates on how to face this issue, My first request with the "Connection" and "Keep-Alive" headers is processed with a warning as you mentioned---> "Refused to set unsafe header 'Connection'." My subsequent request fail. Can you pleae throw some light on this... Thank you